# Обратиться к родительскому элементу Xaml

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Есть следующая структура

```
 <Grid.RenderTransform>
   <CompositeTransform />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />     
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Width="50"
                                    Height="50"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="0,-50,0,0"
                                    ManipulationMode="Rotate"
                                    ManipulationDelta="Button_ManipulationDelta"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource ShowBorder}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityInvertConverter}}" >
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Rotate.png" />
                            </Button.Background>
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                        </Button>

                        <Border Width="670"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                ManipulationDelta="Border_ManipulationDelta"
                                ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY,Rotate,Scale">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                        </Border>

                        <Image  Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                    Margin="{x:Bind Position}"
                                    Width="650"
                                    Source="{x:Bind Image, Converter= {StaticResource UriToImageConverter}}"
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Value"
                                               TargetObject="{StaticResource ShowBorder}"
                                               Value="{Binding Value ,Source={StaticResource ShowBorder}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityInvertConverter}}" />
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
```

Смысл в том, чтобы когда тянешь за `Border` изменял размер его родительский `Grid`

Не могу к нему обратиться из кода

Пробовал так

```
var container = sender as Border;
container = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container);

var ct = (CompositeTransform)(container as Grid).RenderTransform;// получаю Null Reference
//Или так
var ct = (CompositeTransform)container.RenderTransform;// получаю Не может преобразовать MatrixTransform to RenderTransform
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так чтобы тащить нужно было Grid, но только только тогда, когда курсор именно на бордере. Для это использовал события `Poiner_Entered` и `_Exited`. Получается так что мы тащим Grid, но из-за того что он там же где и Border, то визульно кажется что тащим все таки Border. Единственный нюанс, так это картинка мерцает

Для определения, что Border видно использовал:

```
 var grid = sender as Grid;
 var child = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid,3);
```

`3` это индекс контрола сверху вниз, как на рзметке